# Hermitian vs Frobenius inner products?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

(Correct me if I am wrong but) I have concluded that the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) (ip) is the generalization of the complex vectors ip to that of matrices.

My q is wrt whether or not the [Hermitian ip](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) is a limiting case of the Frobenius ip, defined only for square matrices?

Comment: The Hermitian inner product is defined on an arbitrary complex vector space (of finite dimension), whereas the Frobenius inner product applies to a space of operators (over a complex finite dimensional vector space)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Wouldn't the Hermitian ip have to be defined to apply to a space of operators (namely $\left<A,B\right>$) also?

Comment: no ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$